# Automate form filling whose field is powered by Google with Python

Tags: python, forms, selenium, automation

I'm trying to get data from a csv and input in fields of a form with selenium. I managed to do most of it, however the first field which is an address, to be recognized by the form I have to click on the option that appears in a box powered by Google.

Website of form: (Must have registration)
https://indicaai.quintoandar.com.br/

[This is what show powered by google when I write something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeFk3.png)

Any tips on how to resolve this?

Edit:

```
<fieldset>
                                          <span class="sc-bdVaJa Ongdx"><span>Insira o endereço do imóvel e os dados do proprietário para indicar</span></span>
                                          <div data-testid="search-address-container" class="AddressWrapper-cBPhHQ jhZitp">
                                             <div class="SearchBarInnerWrapper-gXtreI jrzXsr">
                                                <div>
                                                   <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root TextValidatorWrapper-jlrQgm fNMjqh MuiFormControl-marginDense MuiFormControl-fullWidth" theme="[object Object]" maxlength="100">
                                                      <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-marginDense Mui-focused Mui-focused" data-shrink="true">Rua*</label>
                                                      <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInput-fullWidth Mui-focused Mui-focused MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl MuiInputBase-marginDense">
                            <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" name="googleApiAddress" placeholder="Exemplo: Av. Paulista, 235" type="text" maxlength="100" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputMarginDense MuiInput-inputMarginDense">
                              </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="AdditionalInfo-dmbwFQ TvjqL"></div>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container">
                                                <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-6">
                                                   <div>
                                                      <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root TextValidatorWrapper-jlrQgm fNMjqh MuiFormControl-marginDense MuiFormControl-fullWidth" theme="[object Object]" maxlength="6">
                                                         <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-marginDense" data-shrink="false">Número*</label>
                                                         <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInput-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl MuiInputBase-marginDense"><input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="address-line2" name="housenumber" type="number" maxlength="6" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputMarginDense MuiInput-inputMarginDense"></div>
                                                      </div>
                                                      <div class="AdditionalInfo-dmbwFQ TvjqL"></div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-6">
                                                   <div class="MuiBox-root jss357 sc-EHOje bYipDz">
                                                      <div>
                                                         <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root TextValidatorWrapper-jlrQgm fNMjqh MuiFormControl-marginDense MuiFormControl-fullWidth" theme="[object Object]" maxlength="100" data-testid="complement">
                                                            <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-marginDense" data-shrink="false">Complemento</label>
                                                            <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInput-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl MuiInputBase-marginDense"><input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="address-level4" name="complement" placeholder="Exemplo: Apto 42" type="text" maxlength="100" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input MuiInputBase-inputMarginDense MuiInput-inputMarginDense"></div>
                                                         </div>
                                                         <div class="AdditionalInfo-dmbwFQ TvjqL"></div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12">
                                                   <div class="MuiBox-root jss358 sc-EHOje bYipDz">
                                                      <div class="MuiBox-root jss359 sc-EHOje bYipDz"><span class="sc-bdVaJa Ongdx"><span>Escolha o tipo de indicação:</span></span></div>
                                                      <div class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12">
                                                         <label class="MuiFormControlLabel-root" theme="[object Object]" color="primary">
                                                            <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss372 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary colorPrimary sc-Rmtcm crdlgZ jss373 Mui-checked checked MuiIconButton-colorPrimary" aria-disabled="false" theme="[object Object]">
                                                               <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                                                                  <input class="jss375" name="forRent" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="" checked="checked">
                                                                  <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
                                                                     <path d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"></path>
                                                                  </svg>
                                                               </span>
                                                               <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                                                            </span>
                                                            <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiFormControlLabel-label MuiTypography-body1"><span>Locação</span></span>
                                                         </label>
                                                         <label class="MuiFormControlLabel-root" theme="[object Object]" color="primary">
                                                            <span class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root jss372 MuiCheckbox-root MuiCheckbox-colorPrimary colorPrimary sc-Rmtcm crdlgZ jss373 Mui-checked checked MuiIconButton-colorPrimary" aria-disabled="false" theme="[object Object]">
                                                               <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
                                                                  <input class="jss375" name="forSale" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="" checked="checked">
                                                                  <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
                                                                     <path d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"></path>
                                                                  </svg>
                                                               </span>
                                                               <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                                                            </span>
                                                            <span class="MuiTypography-root MuiFormControlLabel-label MuiTypography-body1"><span>Venda</span></span>
                                                         </label>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </fieldset>
```

The field is the input with name ="googleApiAddress"

[Illustrative image of the box that opens when typing something in the address field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8koQU.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the html code of the page you are stuck at? It's quite difficult to fill in all the details and reach to the field you've decribed about.

Comment: I put the part of the HTML that has the input field that I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating the details. According to the html and screenshot, once user starts typing an api request is sent and a matching address is suggested in the field.
 Can you try using `sendKeys()` to enter few words of the location and add a `waituntil` till the address suggestion pops-up?
 You can also throw in a `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)` or `sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)` if address pop-up doesn't show up

Comment: Yes, when I use sendKeys() and enter the words the address pops-up nicely, but I don't know how to click it in the option. Sorry, I'm new to python haha

Comment: I've tried to use WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/main/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/fieldset[1]/div/div[3]/ul/li/span')).click(), but I got TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: After the pop-up, inspect element the address you want to select. Copy xpath of the same and use it in your `waituntil` statement and then add a `click()` on the next line for the same xpath. Your address should be selected after this